# Show Category and subcategory in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two arrays: one for categories and second for subcategory. When I parse a category and save it in first array and get subcategory from this array, I want to access the specific subcategories for my category. e.g for 1 index of category array I want to save subcategory array for that.

```
NSDictionary * datas = [dic valueForKey:@"data"];

for(NSArray *data in datas ){
    ParseSubCategoryModel * PSCM = [[ParseSubCategoryModel alloc]init];

    PSCM.ZeroIndex = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    PSCM.OneIndex = [data objectAtIndex:1];
    PSCM.TwoIndex = [data objectAtIndex:2];
    PSCM.THreeIndex = [data objectAtIndex:3];

    NSArray *sub1 = [ PSCM.OneIndex valueForKey:@"sub_categories"];// parse sub_categories here ok he yaha tak
    self.fetchData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.SubSubData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for(NSDictionary *subdic in sub1 ){

        ParseSubCategoryModel * PSCM1 = [[ParseSubCategoryModel alloc]init];
        PSCM1.id_no = [subdic valueForKey:@"_id"];
        PSCM1.name = [subdic valueForKey:@"name"];
        PSCM1.is_active = [subdic valueForKey:@"is_active"];
        PSCM1.url = [subdic valueForKey:@"url"];
        PSCM1.category_order = [subdic valueForKey:@"sub_category_order"];
        PSCM1.updated_at = [subdic valueForKey:@"updated_at"];
        PSCM1.created_at = [subdic valueForKey:@"created_at"];
        [self.fetchData addObject:PSCM1];

        NSArray *subsub1 = [subdic valueForKey:@"sub_subcategories"];//parse sub_subcategories here
        for(NSDictionary *subSubdic  in subsub1 ){

            ParseSubCategoryModel * PSCM2 = [[ParseSubCategoryModel alloc]init];
            PSCM2.id_no = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"_id"];
            PSCM2.name = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"name"];
            PSCM2.is_active = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"is_active"];
            PSCM2.url = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"url"];
            PSCM2.category_order = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"sub_subcategory_order"];
            PSCM2.updated_at = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"updated_at"];
            PSCM2.created_at = [subSubdic valueForKey:@"created_at"];
            [self.SubSubData insertObject:PSCM2 atIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@",self.SubSubData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: every catagory show the sub category of first index.

Comment: if any category have no subcategories it shows the subcategories of first category.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit easy approach to solve your requirement using UITableView section header and cells:

I have tried this method to expand and collapse of UITableview as well:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *categoryArray;
    NSArray *subcategoryArray;
    //This Dictionary is be used to add the Subcategory Array for each category using category ID. 
    NSMutableDictionary *subCategoryDict;
}
@end


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //Returns number of category array as Section
    return categoryArray.count;
}
```

**//Take the NSDictionary or Your Custom Object to get Category ID to pass inside our dictionary to get Subcategory array**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSDictionary *data = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *subcategory = [subCategoryDict valueForKey:[data valueForKeyPath:@"_categoryId"]];

    return subcategory.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *data = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *subcategory = [subCategoryDict valueForKey:[data valueForKeyPath:@"_categoryId"]];
    NSDictionary *subCatData = [subcategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    Cell.textLabel.text = [subCatData valueForKey:@"values"];

    return Cell;
}
```

**You can also use UITableview cell for customisation of header section.
      You need to create UIButton and add subview as Section view for selection make sure you have added tag with value as section.**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    NSDictionary *data = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return view;    
}
```

Hope this will work as per your requirements.

If you want to use custom UITableView then you can look to below code:
https://github.com/genkernel/TreeView